# Propagating rays through an optical system

Tags: optics

For educationnal purposes I'm trying to build my own ray-tracer in the likes of a simplified version of CodeV or Zemax. Nothing beats building something from scratch to fully understand it.

I'm starting in 2D with simple lenses and mirrors. I set up my source, optical elements + stop surface and image plane, for example a Cooke triplet :

[image]

I want to be able to trace the rays from the object to the image and draw a spot diagram versus field position.

I have trouble finding the best way of propagating the rays. Should I trace $N$ rays in a semi-hemisphere out of the source and keep only the ones that hit the first surface ? That seems very inefficient, and unapplicable to objects at infinity.
Maybe I should define a grid of rays that sample the entrance pupil, but then I don't know how to find the location and shape of the EP without tracing the rays backwards from the stop surface. Any help is appreciated.